# reducing repeated words after closure compiler

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I need to reduce repeated words in a closure compiled js file manually, because i can't use gzip on the compiled js file.

I looked at a few ways to do it, for example I wanted to reduce the word "prototype" so what i did was a reference to the prototype in each object and then used that reference in order to add properties and methods to the object prototype, so the word prototype will be used only once for each object. But it seems that the closure compiler is having trouble with removing not used code this way in some cases, as it keeps methods in the object that are not been used by any object down the prototype chain or by this object itself. 
it looks like it can't detect this way if the method is been used by any object down the prototype chain, so it keeps it and making the file size actually larger.

Another thing I tried to do in order to reduce the word "prototype" was using the @nocollapse annotation, but for some reason it breaks the code, the compiled code throws Uncaught ReferenceError about not defined variables and functions when I am trying to use this annotation, or it's just flatten the word, making it been repeated again.

Are there other ways in order to reduce repeated words?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Closure compiler has an `AliasStrings` pass which will help significantly for cases where gzip is not used. It is not enabled nor exposed through a flag. Using it requires a custom build of the compiler.

https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CompilerOptions.java#L442